# Can I expand macro JUST ONE TIME in specific target?

Tags: makefile

```
A = "demo"
%.o:%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $^ $(A) -o $@
default:$(all_objs)
game:A = $(shell read -p 'Enter game version: ' gv && echo $$gv)
game:$(all_objs)
```

Just a snippet makefile above. If I `make game`, main problem is **each compilation of sources will expand $(A) and it will request user to input game version over and over**. $(A) has default content "demo" only if user doesn't make `game` target.

So, is there any way to set $(A) to be expanded  && ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
game:A:=$(shell read -p 'Enter game version: ' gv && echo $$gv)
```

Notice ':='

Update:
Reading user input in real build targets is not a good idea. Make is widely used and whoever invokes it - they wouldn't expect this.

I see two ways to do what you wanted:

1. `make version=some_version`. It will override `version` variable (name may be almost anything). If you have assigned its default value in makefile - it will be changed to `some_version` (unless variable declared with `override` flag, which disables this behaviour)
2. Create `make config` rule, which would perform required configuration actions and save them into, say, config.mk. In makefile you could have `-include config.mk` ('-' sign says make that this file may be missing. If it is required (e.g. contains some mandatory configuration options), remove minus sign).

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry about my carelessness.
I modified my question again. I have `default` target and don't need user input game version. Just `game` target needs that operation only. So I can't use `A:=...` statement(It will expand following macro at 1st phase of make). How can I do?

Comment: I FORCE user to do that(read -p ...) in fact because we always forget to update the game version before the day(or the rushing moment) of the damned release dead line. :)





Your method is still an answer, but busy programmers may forget anything in any moments. Anyway, thanks your answers.

Comment: Weird. I think it should be done with version control tag. But whatever, why `make version=some_vesion` syntax isn't ok for this? You have default value and new value that will be manually typed into make invocation command. Of course it's up to you to decide.

Comment: `make version=some_version` is a regular method, of course. But if we JUST FORGET to add arguments(version=xxx) and build executable out, we can only notice that SOMETHING is missed until customers complained that they don't see the version info.

So I FORCE user to do that to inform he/she: Now we are building final product and you should confirm your version displayed on it. Maybe you feel weird, may I have other suggestions from you about this situation?

Comment: Hard to tell without a full picture. As i've said, getting version tag from version control system seems most logical way, but if it isn't suitable (e.g. you, for some reason, don't use version control) - there are other ways. You could make unspecified version to be an error (assign some default value and check it in makefile with `ifeq`). Or you could make a test that will run automatically after build and send email with resulting build info to build engineer. Whatever, i don't think 'type here anything because build system complains' is a good approach - you'll end with garbage version.

Comment: You provide another ways to archive our goal and thanks for your opinions. Let make raises the error is also a good approach, I'll use it.

It is not we don't use version control system, we can only show version of our customers PREFERRED flavor. So we must modified our displayed version each release time.

Force user enter the desired game version is just a reminder, because we just want to be reminded. We always know what value should be entered.